# mmcblk0p1 is not mounted during boot

Tags: boot, mount

I have a Raspbian Jessie installation where `mmcblkp01` is not mounted. During boot I see this message on the console:

```
 start job running for `dev-mmcblk0p1.device`
```

Eventually this times out and I am dropped into the emergency mode. When I enter the root password I can mount `mmcblk0p1.device` without a problem:

```
 mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot
```

The line in `/etc/fstab` is:

```
 /dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot  vfat  defaults  0  2
```

The `mmcblk0p1` is a normal VFAT partition. The start and end sectors are equal to a working Raspbian installation.

If it is relevant, `sysctl` cannot start `dev-ttyAMA0` either.

Now I can take the easy way and make a fresh install, but I want to understand why this happens. So the main question is, where can I start to search why `mmcblk0p1` is not mounted? Or why the `dev-mmcblk0p1.device` service is not started.

How I ended up here:

Some background information. Raspbian did not start to refuse mounting mmcblk0p1 all by itself. This is the history:

1. I had a working Raspbian Wheezy installation
2. Dist-upgraded that to Jessie (still no problem)
3. Mounted a USB external hard disk as root file system
4. Changed cmdline.txt to use the USB disk as root file system
5. Changed `/etc/fstab` to mount the USB disk on '/' instead of `mmcblk0p2`

I did not touch anything related to `mmcblk0p1` or the boot partition or whatever. When mounting a different device as a root file system there must always be a boot partition on the SD card. That is how the Pi works.

This installation worked all fine. I need the HDD because I am running a 
data logger on a MySQL database and I don't want to wear out the SD card.

Next, I made a full rsync copy of the installation.

The Pi with USB HDD went into production

But I need a shadow system to continue testing and development

This time without external HDD because the Pi is not running continuously.
The development Pi had a Wheezy install.

I took out the SD card from the Pi and mounted it on my desktop machine.

```
sdc2 -> /mnt/pi-root

sdc1 -> /mnt/pi-root/boot
```

`Rsync-ed` the previously made image to the SD card. Modified `cmdline.txt` and `/etc/fstab` to the normal original versions as for using the SD card as root FS.

Placed the SD card back in the Pi and then the problem occurred.

I just want to understand why `mmcblk0p1` is not mounted. I am sure I can solve the problem to get a working system back. But for future projects I want to know how I can clone a production system back into a development system.

Comment: The Foundation **NEVER** provided a `dist-upgrade` from Wheezy to Jessie so you presumably used one of the unsupported kludges. Who knows what you have? Just do a clean installation.

Comment: I did not complain, just tried to understand. The once executed  dist-upgrade went fine as far as I could see. The really stupid thing I did was to copy the Jessie image back to an existing Wheezy SD. Once I created a pristine Jessie minimal SD, copied back my production image and everything was fine. Which is, in fact, amazing as well.